# Choosing projection to make Arizona look "normal"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3, united-states

I am having issues projecting my AZ state boundary from looking like this:

[image]

to looking like this:

[image]

I found that I could use the [U.S. National Atlas Equal Area](https://source.opennews.org/en-US/learning/choosing-right-map-projection/) to get the shape I want, but when I try to project my Arizona Boundary Shapefile, a good geographic transformation doesn't show up.

What is a good coordinate system that I can use as a projection to get my desired shape? For the record, the first shape is GCS_NAD_1983. I'm not sure what the second shape is.

I am using ArcMap 10.3

Comment: Whatever projection that moves Arizona to the left, transforms it to a equal and representative state, and aligns it with it's more progressive neighbors is preferable (IMHO)

Comment: You're funny. :) Come to Flagstaff!

Comment: I was thinking much the same, it may never be normal.

Comment: I agree on the albers point and it is in ArcGIS and will project and define projection. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined WKID: 102039

Put this number into the ArcGIS search bar in projections and it will show up.

I agree with you this will get the shape to appear as you require. It is defined in ArcGIS so you can reproject to and from unprojected NAD 83.

[image]

> USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version
>
> WKID: 102039
>
> Authority: ESRI
>
> Projection: Albers
>
> False_Easting: 0.0
>
> False_Northing: 0.0
>
> Central_Meridian: -96.0
>
> Standard_Parallel_1: 29.5
>
> Standard_Parallel_2: 45.5
>
> Latitude_Of_Origin: 23.0
>
> Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)
>
> Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1983 Angular Unit:
>
> Degree (0.0174532925199433) Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0) Datum:
>
> D_North_American_1983
>
> Spheroid: GRS_1980
>
> Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
>
> Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314140356
>
> Inverse Flattening: 298.257222101

Comment: Thank you for showing me the right projection! Since it is already projected, I went into the toolbox and just chose the "Project" tool to reproject my boundary shapefile. However, the when the new projection loads, the shape looks exactly the same... Would that be caused by using the incorrect Geographic Transformation?

Comment: Start a new arcmap. Then add only the newly reprojected layer. You are running into potf issues

Comment: New fresh blank empty arcmap and then add the new reprojected layer only, not others until this new one is in the map.

Comment: No it's not a problem of the transformaty. Just protection on the fly issues.

Comment: Okay. I opened a new ArcMap, opened my re-projected boundary, and it looks perfect! Thank you!